# NoSuchMethodError for diff version jars

Tags: java

There is a jar which has 2 versions
in version 1 there are majorly 2 classes

```
Class A
Class B

Class A has a constructor as
A(X,B)
```

in version 2 there are majorly 2 classes and an interface

```
Class A
Interface C
Class B implements C

Class A has a constructor as
A(X,C)
```

In my util class I call the constructor of A

```
A a= new A(x,new B());
```

Above code is ant build using jar 1 which builds fine.

Now in production env the jar in classpath is of version 2.
and I am getting error as

```
NoSuchMethodError A.<init>(x;B)
```

Not able to understand that in version 2 jar B is implemention of C so why this error?
Please help me understand

Comment: have you checked all the classes in the jar are the right ones?  When you're building your JAR it might be using old class files

Comment: yes.After doing all this analysis only I have posted this question here.Do remember that my jar was build using version 1 jar in classpath and in prod env version 2 jar is present.Old version didn't has interface but version 2 has.But i am passing the implementation class in my util class which should be accepted by both jars.

Comment: Did you try to run the JAR via command line? When runned this way the console shows the output, thrown exceptions included. `java -jar myJar.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is due to the fact that you are changing the function signature of a *constructor* .** If you check the bytecode of your `Util` class, you will see that it is using `invokespecial`, not `invokevirtual` opcode (*constructors and private methods are called via `invokespecial`*). `invokespecial` is really special in a sense that it does static binding. For a longer explanation I suggest reading this: [article](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/invocationP.html)

> Invokespecial differs from invokevirtual primarily in that
>   invokespecial selects a method based on the type of the reference
>   rather than the class of the object. In other words, it does static
>   binding instead of dynamic binding. In each of the three situations
>   where invokespecial is used, dynamic binding wouldn't yield the
>   desired result.

By that version change you make after compilation, you are actually erasing the only constructor that your Util class can call, and you cannot rely on dynamic binding this time.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is version 1 is still lurking somewhere in your production classpath alongside version 2 and it's the first one your classloader encounter.

In fact you should treat this as a blessing because otherwise you have a tiny silent bug which never cause havoc until some random time in the future when your classloader give you v1 (happens in my previous company and production goes into a grinding halt for a full week).

This is often difficult to debug because version 1 can be injected by another jar, war, by the container, transitively by maven, accidentally when packing the jar/war, osgi bundle, or worse: by a rogue classloader (good luck with this)

If it's taking you forever to solve this I'd rename A version 2 into A2 if I can so it has deterministically different name (yes this is an ugly solution).

Another common cause is JBoss not cleaning itself between multiple redeploys. So when you deploy app version 567, classpath still has junk from version 566. Typically this can be solved by doing a clean deploy (kill JBoss process, delete temp folder, start it again)

Comment: I have checked entire lib folder in JBoss but can find only one jar having the used class.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough, arbitrary version of class can be injected during runtime (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

When the code was complied with version1 jar then class file was generated with constructor having argument as class file (class B) and it didnot had the interface C.
When the same jar was moved to production env, constructor was having interface C (type C) which was not matching with class B (type B) hence the error of nosuchmethoderror.When code was complied with version 2 jar the error got resolved.